# How can I return id from hash value:

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have a contract with a mapping table where I am mapping an id(uint) to hash values. I am able to return hash value from id but what if I wanna do it the other way around, like get id from hash value. Here's the code that I am using:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Hash {
  bytes32 comphash;

  struct hashstruct {   
    bytes32 fhash;
  }

  mapping (uint => hashstruct) hashstructs;
  uint[] public hashAccts;

  function setinstructor(uint _uint,string _fhash) public {
    var a = hashstructs[_uint];

    a.fhash = sha256(_fhash);  

    hashAccts.push(_uint) -1;              
  }

  function getInstructor(uint ins) view public returns (bytes32) {
    return (hashstructs[ins].fhash);
  }

  function count() view public returns (uint) {
    return hashAccts.length;
  }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the hash of your struct into another mapping:

```
mapping(bytes32 => uint) _map;

function setinstructor(uint _uint,string _fhash) public {
  var a = hashstructs[_uint];

  a.fhash = sha256(_fhash);  

  hashAccts.push(_uint) -1;              

  _map[keccak256(a.fhash)] = _uint; // Can pass in other struct members as well
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the response Adam, I tried doing that but I get a compilation error which says: UnimplementedFeatureError: Only in-memory reference type can be stored.

Comment: Apologies...I forgot that `keccak256` can't be used on structs. You can send in each element of your struct as parameters, though. See the edit.

Comment: Of course, I'm assuming your struct is more complex than what you posted. Otherwise, you should just use a simple `bytes32` for `fhash` as a state variable and you can use that value (the sha256) directly in your mapping.